# How to get browser 's download dialog given the url of file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, download

[image]My requirement is to download a file when "Download" button is clicked. Service is giving me the url of the file. I used window.location but it is replacing my page. I just want the default download dialog provided by browser. How do I get that? I am getting a string (file location) from service, not the file. I am using jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried opening a new window pointed to that url?

Comment: Yes, it opens a new window with file contents.

Comment: I would change your code a bit. I would simply open the window to `/Controller/GetFile?ID=1` and have that action return a `FileResult`.

Comment: Tried that, got "http:/someOtherServer/file.txt is not a valid virtual path" error. The file is on a different server but I do have access. If I give url to window.location as shown above, it's opening the file.

Comment: Is the file hosted on a different server?

Comment: Yes and it's a zip file.

Comment: In that case, I think its up to the other server how the file is served. Another alternative would be to read the file using code in your controller, and pass the byte array to the FileResult and return that to the user. Not sure how well that would work.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Comment: Thanks for responses but my code worked fine when the server sends zip file. I had been trying with txt files and browser was opening the file itself in the browser window.